# Can I create an Haskell function that put some strings in a tuple or in a list?

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming, tuples

For example I have a string in input: "aaa bbb ccc dddd" and my function give me

```
["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "dddd"]
```

or

```
("aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "dddd")
```

Is possible?

Comment: Yes that is possible.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We can just reason about the types and then look for the function in Hoogle.

For example, you need a function, which accepts a `String` and returns a list of `String`s, e.g `String -> [String]`. Let's look for it:

https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=String+-%3E+%5BString%5D

The first one is `lines` with a description:

> breaks a string up into a list of strings at newline characters. The resulting strings do not contain newlines.

Hm, but we need to break at spaces, not only at newline characters. Maybe there's something else?

What about `words`?

> breaks a string up into a list of words, which were delimited by white space.

Yea, the right, one.

Thus, the answer is:

You need the [words](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:words) function:

`words "aaa bbb ccc dddd"` returns `["aaa","bbb","ccc","dddd"]`

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @RiccardoMonterisi please accept this answer. There is extra checkbox on the left side, for that.